# Memcached clustered alternative

Tags: memcached

I'm looking to replace memcached. We have a LOT of traffic to our central memcached node which I'd like to split. There's only so much trunking networks I can do.

My general idea is to install a memcached-type daemon on every webserver and have the daemons replicate set/delete/updates over all the daemons, so that each webserver connects to a socket or on localhost. All data should be available on all nodes.

The alternatives:
- repcached (max 2 masters)
- redis (single master)
- couchdb/mongodb/handlersocket - persistent data on disk, I'd like to remove the disk part to gain more performance.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Membase in caching (memory-only) mode, it's memcached-based

Comment: Membase is "Couchbase" now: http://www.couchbase.com/membase

Comment: @Alex, does Couchbase have a (synchronous) replication mechanism between nodes in a cluster?